# having trouble with arabic font rendering correctly android app

Tags: java, android, text, arabic

My android app is not displaying the arabic font correctly on the view that displays the radio player and the text. I get symbols in the arabic text (percent sings, copyright and registered trade mark symbols, double greater thann signs, +/- sign, double commas ... ALL mixed with arabaic characters).

Here is a snippet from the java class file:

```
private void setTypeFace(){
        int os_version = ((MiraathRadio)getApplication()).os_version;
        if(os_version < 9){
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpath);
            audioTitle.setTypeface(tf);

            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpathFroyo2);
            stationTitle.setTypeface(tf);

            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpathmotlak);
            listenerNomber.setTypeface(tf);

        }

        else {

            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpath2);
            audioTitle.setTypeface(tf);

            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpathArabic2);
            stationTitle.setTypeface(tf);

            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpathmotlak);
            listenerNomber.setTypeface(tf);

        }
    }
```

I have installed Tahoma, Froyo, and mcs_jf2 fonts (all TTF) and still it will not render correctly.

I have tried to use a Arabizer and Farsi class file to connect, but to now avail.

I have a screen shot of the problem if anyone wants to see it.

What am I doing wrong???

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!!
ironmantis7x

[image: strange arabic text]

I am posting the code where I am setting the text:

```
private void setTypeFace(){
        int os_version = ((MiraathRadio)getApplication()).os_version;
        if(os_version < 9){
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpath);
            audioTitle.setTypeface(tf);

            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpathFroyo2);
            stationTitle.setTypeface(tf);

            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpathmotlak);
            listenerNomber.setTypeface(tf);

        }

        else {

            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpathArabic3);
            audioTitle.setTypeface(tf);

            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpathArabic3);
            stationTitle.setTypeface(tf);

            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpathArabic3);
            listenerNomber.setTypeface(tf);
```

I am lost here. Any pointers and help would be great.

ironmantis7x

Comment: Have you tried with different Arabic Fonts..??

Comment: Yes I have ... thing is, what arabic font would be the best to use???

Comment: which one looks good that will be best. you can verify it only by implementing it.

Comment: Thanks.  I hate sound stupid: can you please make a recommendation for two or three arabic TTF that work in android app?

Comment: [Check this app](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?tab=ww&ei=5gcEVIuyGtCgugT-gYK4Bg&ved=0CBMQ1S4#q=arabic%20fonts%20for%20android) you'll found several FontNames which is working for Android app. :)

Comment: I tried aljazeera, nask, Muhammed and none of them worked.

Comment: It was the same results as the picture...

Comment: I tried several arabic fonts (aljazeera,  nashk, Muhammed to name a few) and the results are the same in the picture...

Comment: I tried roboto and Dejavu and the same error exists ...

Comment: no matter what font i use - it always comes out like the above screen capture. Is there a way to take care of this??? I am using Android studio ver 0.8.X.

Comment: Will you show me which text you are setting to the TextView.?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long @SilentKiller ...
New code posted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alhamdulillah!!!
Found the issue!!!

The encoding was wrong ...
The previous developer put "windows-1256" as the encoding type.
I changed it to "utf-8" and it works just fine!!!

Thanks everyone for all your help!!!